# Using RegExp or split in rawdata string using C#

Tags: regex

I want split or parse this using regexp but there's a catch that I need to have something to compare it whenI parse it. Here's the data string

```
"351856040666992,RA1;2400A1444.5122N12030.5764E026.3150.000.900057031451271113EFA2524018D1430DF90F,,,,,,,,"
```

what I want to have as result is something like this. Yes I can parse the first 11 digits but the next I cant.

Here's the result I need.

```
351856040666992
RA1
2400
A
1444.5122N
12030.5764E
026.3
150.0
00.9
00057
031451
271113
EF
A2
52
40
18D
143
0DF90F
```

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what rules you want this parsing to follow? Is it by position (e.g. column 0-14), delineation (e.g. until the comma), or another means?

Comment: I want to parse it by like this:1st 15 characters then 2nd 3 characters then 3rd 4 characters and so on so forth. While removing all commas and periods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex works for that. Converted here to c#:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
... 
string my_string = "351856040666992,RA1;2400A1444.5122N12030.5764E026.3150.000.900057031451271113EFA2524018D1430DF90F,,,,,,,,";
string my_regex = "(.{15})[.,;]*(.{3})[.,;]*(.{4})[.,;]*(.{1})[.,;]*(.{10})[.,;]*(.{11})[.,;]*(.{5})[.,;]*(.{5})[.,;]*(.{4})[.,;]*(.{5})[.,;]*(.{6})[.,;]*(.{6})[.,;]*(.{2})[.,;]*(.{2})[.,;]*(.{2})[.,;]*(.{2})[.,;]*(.{3})[.,;]*(.{3})[.,;]*(.{6})";
Regex r = new Regex(my_regex);
foreach (Group g in r.Match(my_string).Groups) {
    Console.WriteLine(g);
}
```

Prints:

```
351856040666992
RA1
2400
A
1444.5122N
12030.5764E
026.3
150.0
00.9
00057
031451
271113
EF
A2
52
40
18D
143
0DF90F
```

Note that is **only** works if every line you want to parse has the same number of characters per field. I suspect this may not be the case given that `1444.5122N` and `12030.5764E` have different lengths, but seem to have the same intended function.

Second note: If using in production code, remember to check the `Success` property of the `Match` object before trying to iterate over its groups.

Comment: Thanks. I will now find a way to convert this to C#.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found a way to do it. Here's my answer so as to help others as well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sample
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection cnn;
        //string connectionString = "server=ACER-PC;database=YourDatabaseName;user id=;pwd=";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        //string str = "351856040666992,RA1;2400A1444.5122N12030.5764E026.3150.000.900057031451271113EFA2524018D1430DF90F,,,,,,,,";
        //string str = "351856040520447,241111;1G,?130903011053,A,0628.9385N,12451.8013E,0.0,71,0.9,00004000;";
        string str = "@P,7FC5,117,0,359551035057990,20130905094454,20130905094455,20130905094455,121000369,14507155,0,2,0,8,1,0,0,0,,2000,2000,";
        if (str.Length == 105)
        {
            //FOR ARKNAV(R10-V2) Raw Data Definition
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i = i + 8)
            {
                //IMEI
                string imei = str.Substring(i, 15);
                //FIRMWARE
                string firm = str.Substring(16, 3);
                //ACTIVATION STATUS
                string actstat = str.Substring(20, 4);
                //GPS DATA
                string gpsdata = str.Substring(24, 1);
                //LAT
                string lat = str.Substring(25, 10);
                //LONG
                string longit = str.Substring(35, 11);
                //SPEED ON GROUND
                string speedg = str.Substring(46, 5);
                //COURSE ON GROUND
                string courseg = str.Substring(51, 5);
                //HDOP
                string hdop = str.Substring(56, 4);
                //ALTITUDE
                string alt = str.Substring(60, 5);
                //TIME
                string time = str.Substring(65, 6);
                //DATE
                string date = str.Substring(71, 6);
                //POWER SUPPLY INPUT VOLTAGE
                string psupp = str.Substring(77, 2);
                //OB Backup batt storage
                string obbattstor = str.Substring(79, 2);
                //Digital high voltage input status
                string dgitalvoltinpstat = str.Substring(81, 2);
                //Digital outputs status
                string digoutstat = str.Substring(83, 2);
                //ANALOG INPUT 1
                string aninput1 = str.Substring(85, 3);
                //ANALOG INPUT 2
                string aninput2 = str.Substring(88, 3);
                //KM Run
                string kmrun = str.Substring(91, 6);

                Console.WriteLine(imei);
                Console.WriteLine(firm);
                Console.WriteLine(actstat);
                Console.WriteLine(gpsdata);
                Console.WriteLine(lat);
                Console.WriteLine(longit);
                Console.WriteLine(speedg);
                Console.WriteLine(courseg);
                Console.WriteLine(hdop);
                Console.WriteLine(alt);
                Console.WriteLine(time);
                Console.WriteLine(date);
                Console.WriteLine(psupp);
                Console.WriteLine(obbattstor);
                Console.WriteLine(dgitalvoltinpstat);
                Console.WriteLine(digoutstat);
                Console.WriteLine(aninput1);
                Console.WriteLine(aninput2);
                Console.WriteLine(kmrun);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        //FOR ARKNAV(RX8W) Raw Data Definition
        else if (str.Length == 85)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i = i + 8)
            {
                //IMEI
                string imei = str.Substring(i, 15);
                //ProdID
                string prodid = str.Substring(16, 6);
                //with GPS clock
                string clock = str.Substring(23, 2);
                //date time
                string datetime = str.Substring(27, 12);
                //GPS Status
                string gpsstat = str.Substring(40, 1);
                //LAT
                string lat = str.Substring(42, 10);
                //LONG
                string longit = str.Substring(53, 11);
                //Speed
                string speed = str.Substring(65, 3);
                //Course
                string course = str.Substring(69, 2);
                //HDOP
                string hdop = str.Substring(72, 3);
                //Status Code
                string statcode = str.Substring(76, 8);

                Console.WriteLine(imei);
                Console.WriteLine(prodid);
                Console.WriteLine(clock);
                Console.WriteLine(datetime);
                Console.WriteLine(gpsstat);
                Console.WriteLine(lat);
                Console.WriteLine(longit);
                Console.WriteLine(speed);
                Console.WriteLine(course);
                Console.WriteLine(hdop);
                Console.WriteLine(statcode);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        else if (str.Length == 121)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i = i + 8)
            {
                //Prefix
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(i, 2));
                //CRC Check
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(3, 4));
                //Length of the packet
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(8, 3));
                //sequence ID
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(12, 1));
                //IMEI
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(14, 15));
                //GPS Date Time
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(30, 14));
                //RTC Date Time
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(45, 14));
                //Position Sending Date Time
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(60, 14));
                //Longitude
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(75, 9));
                //Latitude
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(85, 8));
                //Heading
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(94, 1));
                //Report ID
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(96, 1));
                //Odometer
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(98, 1));
                //GPS HDOP
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(100, 1));
                //Input Status
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(102, 1));
                //GPS/VSS Vehicle Speed
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(104, 1));
                //Output Status
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(106, 1));
                //Analog Input Value
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(108, 1));
                //Driver ID
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(109, 2));
                //First Temperature Sensor Value
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(111, 4));
                //Second Temperature Sensor Value
                Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(116, 4));
                //Text message
                Console.ReadLine();
            } 
        }
    }
}
}
```

In connection to this I would like to add a follow up question. Where will and what will I insert if I want to Insert the  parsed data which I stored in a variable to MS SQL?